# Visual Studio - 'View Code' not working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am a newby to visual studio and C#, but challenging myself to learn it.  I 'mastered' Matlab a few years ago, but always wanted to learn C#.

I'm using Visual Studio Community to have a go at creating a very basic Windows Application Form.

My biggest stumbling block at the moment is how Design window and code window work together.

They seem disconnected -- for example, if I change things in Design window and select 'View Code' there is nothing extra in the code window (i.e. no colour changes, buttons added etc).  Similarly, if I manually code the form in the code windows, the design window does not change. If I press F5 visual studio only compiles whatever is in the design window, ignoring whatever code is written in the code window.

Is this normal? I was expecting Design and code window to work back-to-back reflecting changes either way. i.e. I could add a button in design window, then the code would be visible. Or I could code a button, then it would be visible in design window.

Thanks in advance!!

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio breaks these your window classes into two files known as [partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

- a designer file: where it keeps all the code related to your window widgets, layout, positioning, etc.
- a code behind file: where you can write your business/controller logic for your design window.

You can interact with the widgets in your design window through events.  For example: double clicking on a button in the design window will add an "On Clicked" event to your code behind.  Single clicking on a widget will bring up a properties screen and allow you to choose other events/hooks you want to tie into.